# Can't access Xilinix SDK 2019.1 application templates

Tags: xilinx

Title explains most of it. When I create a new application project in Xilinx SDK 2019.1 and get to the templates window, the only two available options are 'Empty Application' and 'Opencv Example Application'.

When I look in the /tools/Xilinx/SDK/2019.1/data/embeddedsw directory (which is the default SDK installation repository listed ) I can find many more templates under lib/sw_apps. Directories such as hello_world, and in particular zynq_fsbl which I am looking to use, are in there.

I would like to know how I can actually use these templates and why they are not showing up when creating a new application project.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Target Software language of the application project must be C to access these templates. I was trying to use C++.